# How to write a MySQL query for searching data within two tables under conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a search bar on a website for a inbox; searching sender name and message as I type in search bar that display result with username and their profile pic and message. Just like WhatsApp search bar, where you can search any sender name and any message.

For that, I have two tables. First one name is `user` and second table name is `inbox`. Both having column like:

`user - uid,name,lastname,profile_pic,address,dob`.

`inbox - id,msg_to,msg_from,msg,time,latestmsg,opened`.

I want to search data that can be any user name and can be any word of message, from both tables. 
So, how should be this query design?

I had designed a query in following way:

```
 SELECT u.name
         , u.lastname
         , u.profile_pic
         , i.msg_from
         ,i.msg_to
         , i.msg,i.time
      from user
         , inbox i
     where 
         (
           u.uid=i.msg_from LIKE '%$search%'
        OR u.uid=i.msg_to LIKE '%$search%'
         )  
       AND
         (
           i.msg_to='$uid' LIKE '%$search%' 
        OR i.msg_from='$uid' LIKE '%$search%'
         ) 
       AND u.uid!=$uid 
       AND latestmsg=1
     GROUP 
        BY i.id DESC
```

But, it is not working.

By the way, the query for displaying username and message alongside profile pic (just like WhatsApp and any chatting system) is :

```
SELECT u.name,
       u.lastname,
       u.profile_pic,
       i.msg_from,
       i.msg_to,
       i.msg,
       i.time
FROM user u,
     inbox i
WHERE (u.uid=i.msg_from
       OR u.uid=i.msg_to)
  AND (i.msg_to='$uid'
       OR i.msg_from='$uid')
  AND u.uid!=$uid
  AND latestmsg=1
GROUP BY i.id DESC
```

Comment: Is that a rhetorical question?

Comment: yes it is...but suggestions are also welcome

Comment: As it is a theoretical question I would prefer inner joining two tables then use where clause. Then It would be easy to understand.

Comment: What are you attempting to do with `u.uid=i.msg_from LIKE '%$search%'` is this checking `i.msg_from LIKE '%$search%'` or `u.uid=i.msg_from`?

Comment: `(u.uid=i.msg_from OR u.uid=i.msg_to) AND (i.msg_to='$uid' OR i.msg_from='$uid' )` this is a condition for displaying data from two tables, i want to ask that have I placed `LIKE  '%$search%'` on correct place or not; because search contents are not displaying with this query.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. There are two variables (`$uid` and `%$search%`), so you seem to be looking for a particular user and searching for something, but what? The `GROUP BY` doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: I *suppose* you simply want `select * from comnet_inbox i join comnet_user_details u on u.uid in (i.msg_from, i.msg_to) and u.id <> '$uid' where '$uid' in (i.msg_from, i.msg_to) and i.latestmsg = 1`.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner...i have added more details about it. I hope now it will clear you more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a first look

You should not use old sintax based on implicit  join  but use explicit sintax

```
SELECT distinct u.name
  ,u.lastname
  ,u.profile_pic
  ,i.msg_from
  ,i.msg_to
  ,i.msg,i.time 
from comnet_user_details u
INNER JOIN  comnet_inbox i ON 
  (u.uid=i.msg_from LIKE '%$search%' OR u.uid=i.msg_to LIKE '%$search%')  
  AND 
  (i.msg_to='$uid' LIKE '%$search%' OR i.msg_from='$uid' LIKE '%$search%') 
  AND 
  u.uid!=$uid AND latestmsg=1 
   ORDER BY i.id DESC";
```

You should not use group by if yoy don't use aggregation function ,, you should use DISTINCT (in most recente version of mysql the use of group by withut aggreation function produce error and in the others version produce unpredictable result )

Could be that you are  looking for an ORDER BY DESC instead

You should also  not use PHP var in sql, you are at risk for sqlinjecttion
you should take a look  at your php db driver  for prepared  statement and bindig param

This a simplified  version for let you see a (probaly) correct use of the column involved in join and search

```
SELECT u.name
         , u1.lastname lastname_from
         , u1.profile_pic profile_pic_from
         , u2.lastname lastname_to
         , u2.profile_pic profile_pic_to
         , i.msg_from
         , i.msg_to
         , i.msg 
         , i.time
FROM comnet_inbox 
INNER JOIN comnet_user_details u1 ON  u1.uid=i.msg_from
INNER JOIN comnet_user_details u2 ON u1.uid=i.msg_to
WHERE i.msg LIKE concat('%', $search,'%')
ORDER BY i.id DESC
```

Comment: i implemented it as you say, but search contents are still not appearing

Comment: for the check result  .. you  should update  your question add  a proper data sample  ..  and the expected  result  ..

Comment: ok, i have added details now.

Comment: i asked  for data sample  .. but i don't see this  info  ...

Comment: you may check it in the question details now

Comment: i have read you comment  .. to the question but is not cleat  what your are looking for ... so  (i repeat) update  your question add  a proper data sample  and the expected  result  ..  (your condition seems wrong to me but i can't suggest you the solution if you don't show a clear sample )

Comment: @Iffat Khan: The main problem seems to be your conditions formed `u.uid = i.msg_from LIKE '%$search%'`. There is `=` and `LIKE` in there. The first part `u.uid = i.msg_from` results in true or false, which you then compare with a search pattern. This doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: @scaisEdge  I want to make a search bar for my website's messaging system just like in WhatsApp where you can search any sender in your inbox list and can search any message according to the term you write in a search bar... By "data sample" , do you mean the whole coding page?

Comment: no .. for data sample i mean only  a simple data set (table rows)  for the table involved  and the data set (select result) for the result .. so i can see starting for the  initial data set the result you are looking for ..  and based  on this sample i can think at the query you really need

Comment: ok, i'll update it

Comment: i have attach a screenshot of both tables

Comment: Ok  .. but add also the expected  result  ..  based on a value for $search

Comment: ok...should it also be in a table form in phpmyadmin

Comment: @scaisEdge "based on a value for $search" query is not working, thats why i have attached a screenshot of displaying data on my page in which i have to perfome search

Comment: asnwer updated  with a simplified  version for see the correct use of join